# 'Series' Object Mutable, thus they cannot be hashed. Trying to select rows based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

My DataFrame Heading Columns:
[Country, Date, Death, Confirmed, Recovered]

```
df.loc(df['Country'] == UK)
```

keeps returning the error 'Series' object mutable, cannot be hashed.
Tried also with

```
df.loc(df['Country'].str.contains(UK))
```

doesn't work either.

Dtypes of the columns: [Object, Date, Int, Int, Int]
Tried to change first column to string but the dtype doesn't change

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].astype(str)
```

Comment: try it with the square brackets: `df.loc[df['Country'] == 'UK']`

Comment: object means string only. you can use your keyword with single quotes : 'UK'

Comment: I tried it with 'UK' and still it have the same problem

Comment: Did you try it with square brackets?

Comment: I used another method by extracting the column value first with 
uk = df['Country'] == 'UK'
df = df[uk]
This worked, but I dont get why (df.loc) doesn't work

Comment: square bracket like df.loc(df['Country'] == ['UK'])?